# arrange 1st half left and the rest right

Tags: javascript, css, css-float

how to arrange the first half left and the second half right?
*(instead of the first goes left, second goes right, 3rd goes let, 4th goes right and so on)*

Javascript:

```
  do {
    document.querySelector("main").innerHTML += 
      "<div class='timeTable'>" + 
      tempTime.format("DD-MM-YY | HH:mm") + 
      " - " + tempTime.add(30, "minutes").format("HH:mm") + 
      "</div>";
  } while (tempTime.format("HH:mm") != "19:00");
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.timeTable {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

PS: btw tempTime is a momentjs object (which is irrelevant to the question and just in case somebody is wondering)

Answer (score 0):

found it:

```
main {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(9,auto);
        grid-auto-flow: column;
    }
```

repeat(9,auto) because of 18 boxes ... divided by 2 is 9

EDIT:
basically the question was how to arrange lets say 6 (for easier understanding - instead of 18)
in the question the are as follows:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

in the answer (which was also asked for) they are like this:

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).